# How to find face, eyes from photo/image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, opencv, image-processing

I am doing my project regarding image processing in c#. Here I don't know, how to find face, eyes from image (not webcam). The image will be stored in a specific folder. I am installing EmguCv package, but it not at all work. What are my questions means,

Is Emgu CV works Window 8 OS?

I am searching via net, all the contents are related to find face through webcam. But I want to find a face from photo/image. Please tell the solution.

Which is compatible image processing library for windows 8 and Visual Studio 2010?

Is there any source code satisfies my certain condition. Please post here.

Thank you.

Comment: SO isn't right place to ask for a library or a tool. Usually a question should be focused on a specific restricted topic and, often, provide some code to start with (and to _prove_ your own effort).

Comment: have you seen this url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368709/c-sharp-detect-face-and-crop-image

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SDK. [Aforge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) should be what you need. Try looking at some of the examples provided from their own source code to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned EmguCV is a dot-net port of famous library named OpenCV with good reliability that you can count on it and do your project.What's more, thanks to its nature which is a library (dll) you could easily use it in your project and run wherever CLR is running, including windows 8 OS.